# Sumar las columnas amount de la paginación

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente código, requiero sumar los campos `amount` de la paginación, pero como tengo un `groupBy` suma solo el primero de los registros repetidos:

```
$badges = Badge::groupBy('code')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25);
$total_parcial = $badges->sum('amount');
```

Sí trato de hacer la consulta y agrego la paginación:

```
$badges = Badge::groupBy('code')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25);
$total_parcial = Badge::sum('amount')->paginate(25);
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
Error
Call to a member function paginate() on float
```

Comment: La suma la debes hacer en un `select(DB::raw('SUM(..)'))`, llamar al método `sum()` de collections te retorna un float tal y como dice allí.

Comment: Lo hice de esta manera, pero no me funciona: `$total_parcial = Badge::select(DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total_parcial'))->groupBy('amount')->paginate(25);`

Comment: Tampoco así `$total_parcial = Badge::select(DB::raw('SUM(amount)'))->paginate(25);`

Comment: Te adelanto que la propia [documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results) indica que la paginación junto con la agrupación no trabajan del todo bien

Comment: Que podría hacer en este caso?

Comment: Cómo indica la propia documentación, una paginación de forma manual

Comment: Gracias, eso haré!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$total_parcial = Badge::select('code', DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total_parcial'))
  ->groupBy('code')
  ->paginate(25);
```

Para utilizar groupBy a menudo vas a necesitar una **[Funciones de agregación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)** para tomar un valor por cada grupo que retorne la consulta, en tu caso, por cada código (`code`) que encuentre, tomará la suma de todos ellos.

Comment: Gracias, lo tendré presente... Pero aún no funciona :(

Comment: Deberías poner algunos datos que tienes en tu base de datos y luego poner cómo esperas obtener esos datos agrupados. Es decir, pon un ejemplo de lo que quieres obtener.

Comment: Para esa consulta solo sumar todos los campos `amount` de esta manera lo hace: `$total = Badge::sum('amount'); ` pero ese es el total general, ahora necesito si hago la paginación, me muestre el total de lo que se muestra en cada página.

Comment: Seguramente con la paginación de Laravel no te *alcanzará* por el tema de la agruación, ahí recomiendo pienses en una paginación hecha manualmente